# mysql create function with fulltext search for all words in a single column matching with another table

Tags: mysql, function, full-text-search

I have two tables - one(two columns) is on product items(description) with product code and another with only product description (raw/survey data). The raw data may or may not match with the first one. I would like to match each row of the second table with the product code of the first table. My tables look like as:

```
   Table A (two columns)
   proddescrip      code

   rice,husked      2501
   rice, paddy      0113
   pumpkin, fresh   0123

   Table B (single column)

   description

   rice, local 
   pumpkin 
   ......
```

Now I would like to produce a table C with fulltext search feature of mysql as:

```
 Table C

 description    code 
 rice, local    2501
 pumpkin        0123
```

I thought of creating stored function and apply that instead of running fulltext feature for all rows separately. But it didn't work. Can you suggest me how to approach this problem? I would be grateful if you also advice me with specifics.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but something about this question did remind me of [this answer, where I created a stored function to allow fulltext search to work with non-constant values](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44986/11651) (for purposes of a join).  I don't think it's really what you are looking for, because stored functions can only return scalars, but perhaps it will be of interest.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried that function but it didn't work. All I am trying to do is that mapping table B with table A and get the corresponding code where words of the column in A has a good match with those in table B. I have also worked on a procedure instead of function but gave me partial results. You can have a look at the procedure that I posted in another question just today.